# Large csv parsing CPU improvement

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, csv

I have around 150mb csv file that i need to download, parse and process every 5 minutes. However i am looking to reduce the cpu intensity of this operation as on AWS instance it's eating up around 15% of the cpu.

I am using fast-csv library for node like so:

```
request('https://LinkToTheCSVDownloadable.csv')
  .pipe(csv({
       headers: true
   }))
  .on('data', function (data) {
      objectFilter(data);
   })
  .on('end', function () {
    return callback(filteredObjects);
  })
```

The reason i am doing is to detect whether any new objects/rows have been introduced in the csv file that match my filter criteria. The most CPU intensive task is just parsing through that csv file, even if i don't run every row through the objectFilter method it is using up around 13% of the CPU.

Do you have any suggestions that you maybe have come across before or anything like that so i could potentially reduce the percentage by even a little? Maybe there is a better library out there, or maybe i would be better off writing my own?

I have also read somewhere that the V8 engine and node aren't werent good with GC and an option might be to periodically manage the garbage manually? Could that reduce the CPU?

Thanks!

Comment: Asking for a library or software suggestions will get your question closed as they are not allowed here. Your question needs to be more specific and not venture into opinion.

Comment: I'm not directly asking for a library suggestion, but more on how i could reduce the CPU intensity. Including the library is just to provide more information about what i'm currently using, surely that's fine

Comment: One good strategy is to preprocess the csv file and generate another csv file that contains only unprocessed lines. You can do this without parsing, simply diff the two files. Even better, since lines are only added to the end of file you can even just stat the old file to find out how big it is and then seek to it in the new file (the position argument to fs.read). Be sure to handle cases where the file is incomplete when you downloaded it

Comment: @slebetman I like your suggestion a lot actually, i will try and implement the two suggestions you have given me here and see which one eats less of the CPU. Move your comment to an answer and i will mark it as answered! :)

Comment: @slebetman Ive been trying to figure out how to compare two csvs without parsing for the last couple of days, but i can't seem to get anywhere.. Could you give me a hint on how i could do this to find what rows have been deleted from the previous file and what rows are new?

Comment: Literally `diff`. There are several diffing algorithms available on npm but you can just execute the `diff` program to do it then parse the output to figure out the changes.